# How to click an element which is invisible in Selenium WebDriver using C#?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My code is:

```
Actions a = new Actions(driver);
            a.MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Master Data"))).Build().Perform();
            driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Suppliers")).Click();
```

But it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You have two approaches. Selenium has been specifically written to NOT allow interaction with hidden elements. The rationale is that if a person cannot perform that action, then neither should Selenium. Therefore, to perform the click via Selenium, you must perform the action a user would do to make that button visible (e.g mouseover event, click another element, etc) then perform the click once visible.

However, Selenium does allow you to execute Javascript within the context of an element, so you could write Javascript to perform the click event even if it is hidden.

> To click on a hidden element, you can use JavascriptExecutor with the
>   parameter "arguments[0].click();"

```
element = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Suppliers")).Click();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```